# Помогите адаптировать код под cogs(discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
from  discord.ext import commands
import random

class game(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, Bot):
        self.Bot = Bot

player1 = ""
player2 = ""
turn = ""
gameOver = True

board = []

winningConditions = [
[0, 1, 2],
[3, 4, 5],
[6, 7, 8],
[0, 3, 6],
[1, 4, 7],
[2, 5, 8],
[0, 4, 8],
[2, 4, 6]
]

@commands.commands()
async def tictactoe(ctx, p1: discord.Member, p2: discord.Member):
    global count
    global player1
    global player2
    global turn
    global gameOver

    if gameOver:
        global board
        board = [":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:"]
        turn = ""
        gameOver = False
        count = 0

        player1 = p1
        player2 = p2

    # print the board
        line = ""
        for x in range(len(board)):
            if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                line += " " + board[x]
                await ctx.send(line)
                line = ""
            else:
                line += " " + board[x]

    # determine who goes first
        num = random.randint(1, 2)
        if num == 1:
            turn = player1
            await ctx.send("Это ход <@" + str(player1.id) + ">")
        elif num == 2:
            turn = player2
        await ctx.send("Это ход <@" + str(player2.id) + ">")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Игра уже идет полным ходом! Закончите его, прежде чем начинать новый.")

@commands.command()
async def place(ctx, pos: int):
    global turn
    global player1
    global player2
    global board
    global count
    global gameOver

    if not gameOver:
        mark = ""
        if turn == ctx.author:
            if turn == player1:
                mark = ":regional_indicator_x:"
            elif turn == player2:
                mark = ":o2:"
            if 0 < pos < 10 and board[pos - 1] == ":white_large_square:" :
                board[pos - 1] = mark
                count += 1

            # print the board
                line = ""
                for x in range(len(board)):
                    if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                        line += " " + board[x]
                        await ctx.send(line)
                        line = ""
                    else:
                        line += " " + board[x]

                checkWinner(winningConditions, mark)
                print(count)
                if gameOver == True:
                    await ctx.send(mark + " победили!")
                elif count >= 9:
                    gameOver = True
                    await ctx.send("Это ничья!")

            # switch turns
                if turn == player1:
                    turn = player2
                elif turn == player2:
                    turn = player1
            else:
                await ctx.send("Обязательно выберите целое число от 1 до 9 (включительно)")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Это не ваш ход.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, начните новую игру, используя команду !tictactoe @pl1, @pl2.")


def checkWinner(winningConditions, mark):
    global gameOver
    for condition in winningConditions:
        if board[condition[0]] == mark and board[condition[1]] == mark and board[condition[2]] == mark:
            gameOver = True

@tictactoe.error
async def tictactoe_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, отметье двух игроков для этой команды..")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, не забудьте упомянуть игрока. (ie. <@688534433879556134>).")

@place.error
async def place_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, введите позицию.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, введите целое число.")

def setup(Bot):
    Bot.add_cog(game(Bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
from  discord.ext import commands

import random

class game(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, Bot):
        self.Bot = Bot

        self.player1 = ""
        self.player2 = ""
        self.turn = ""
        self.gameOver = True
        self.board = []

        self.winningConditions = [
                [0, 1, 2],
                [3, 4, 5],
                [6, 7, 8],
                [0, 3, 6],
                [1, 4, 7],
                [2, 5, 8],
                [0, 4, 8],
                [2, 4, 6]
            ]
        
    def checkWinner(self, winningConditions, mark):
        for condition in winningConditions:
            if self.board[condition[0]] == mark and self.board[condition[1]] == mark and self.board[condition[2]] == mark:
                self.gameOver = True

    @commands.commands()
    async def tictactoe(self, ctx, p1:discord.Member, p2:discord.Member):
        if self.gameOver:
            self.board = [
                    ":white_large_square:", 
                    ":white_large_square:", 
                    ":white_large_square:",
                    ":white_large_square:", 
                    ":white_large_square:", 
                    ":white_large_square:",
                    ":white_large_square:", 
                    ":white_large_square:", 
                    ":white_large_square:"
                ]
            self.turn = ""
            self.gameOver = False
            self.count = 0

            self.player1 = p1
            self.player2 = p2

            # print the board
            line = ""
            for x in range(len(self.board)):
                if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                    line += " " + self.board[x]
                    await ctx.send(line)
                    line = ""
                else:
                    line += " " + self.board[x]

            # determine who goes first
            num = random.randint(1, 2)
            if num == 1:
                self.turn = player1
                await ctx.send("Это ход <@" + str(player1.id) + ">")
            elif num == 2:
                self.turn = player2
            await ctx.send("Это ход <@" + str(player2.id) + ">")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Игра уже идет полным ходом! Закончите его, прежде чем начинать новый.")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def place(self, ctx, pos:int):
        if not self.gameOver:
            mark = ""
            if self.turn == ctx.author:
                if self.turn == self.player1:
                    mark = ":regional_indicator_x:"
                elif self.turn == self.player2:
                    mark = ":o2:"
                if 0 < pos < 10 and self.board[pos - 1] == ":white_large_square:" :
                    self.board[pos - 1] = mark
                    self.count += 1

                # print the board
                    line = ""
                    for x in range(len(self.board)):
                        if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                            line += " " + self.board[x]
                            await ctx.send(line)
                            line = ""
                        else:
                            line += " " + self.board[x]

                    self.checkWinner(self.winningConditions, mark)
                    print(self.count)
                    if self.gameOver == True:
                        await ctx.send(mark + " победили!")
                    elif self.ount >= 9:
                        self.gameOver = True
                        await ctx.send("Это ничья!")

                # switch turns
                    if self.turn == self.player1:
                        self.turn = self.player2
                    elif self.turn == self.player2:
                        turn = self.player1
                else:
                    await ctx.send("Обязательно выберите целое число от 1 до 9 (включительно)")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Это не ваш ход.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, начните новую игру, используя команду !tictactoe @pl1, @pl2.")

    @tictactoe.error
    async def tictactoe_error(self, ctx, error):
        print(error)
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, отметье двух игроков для этой команды..")
        elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
            await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, не забудьте упомянуть игрока. (ie. <@688534433879556134>).")

    @place.error
    async def place_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, введите позицию.")
        elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
            await ctx.send("Пожалуйста, введите целое число.")

def setup(Bot):
    Bot.add_cog(game(Bot))
```

Я просто адаптировал Ваш код под ког, поэтому не могу гарантировать, что он будет работать.